# Terminal unable to recognize pod file

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

im trying to install Firebase pods into my pod file but when I run the $pod install or pod init  command terminal returns with this error message "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
I have downloaded all the sdk and lists that firebase requires to run to my project yet still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your project directory by terminal and then write

   pod init

then see your project directory , you will see a pod file .

instruction: to go your project directory write cd and then drug and drop your folder to terminal.

if it not works , then your pc have no cocoa pods. install cocoapod .
to install cocoa pod write the code bellow in terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then follow step 1 again.

hope problem will be solved.
happy coding :)